# Updating Out of the Box SharePoint 2007

Tags: cumulative-update, patching

If I were to re-install SharePoint Server 2007 out of the box - What is the update process to get to SP2 Cumulative Update April 2011?

- Can I simply install the WSS and MOSS CU files or do I need to install SP2 first?
- And if so does SP2 have any pre-requisites?
- Will I need to install the infrastructure updates as well?
- Does WSS or MOSS get installed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263467%28v=office.12%29.aspx#section3) as it is almost precisely your question though uses the Oct update instead of April.  Basically the same steps though.

The article is very detailed but the essential steps are:

On all servers:

- Install Moss
- Install WSS SP2
- Install MOSS SP2
- Install WSS CU
- Install MOSS CU

After all bits are installed on all servers, run the configuration wizard on each server.